# R: Save ksvm value output into working directory

Tags: r

I am currently using the `kernlab` package in `R` to classify incoming data against a set of trained data with the use of an SVM. To do this I use a string kernel, which is set up with the following command:

```
sk <- stringdot(length = 2, lambda = 1.1, type = "exponential", normalized = TRUE)
```

I then feed the calibrated string kernel, `sk`, into the SVM with the following command:

```
svm <- ksvm(xtrain,ytrain,type="C-svc",kernel=sk,C=10,scaled=c())
```

This generates a Formal class ksvm value in the R environment which is then used to predict the classification of the incoming data. The following command is used to classify the new data:

```
predicted <- matrix(predict(svm,xtest))
```

The entire process is quite lengthy. It would save a lot of time if I was able to save the value `svm` and call it to predict the incoming data without having to generate it every time.

Is there any way to save this `svm` value into the working directory and load it up when needed in order to reduce computation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `dput()` for that:

```
dput(svm, "myfile.dput")
rm(svm)
svm <- dget("myfile.dput")
```

or with `save()`:

```
save(svm, file="myfile.RData")
rm(svm)
load("myfile.RData")
```

Comment: `dput()` seems to be a nice, elegant way to solve the problem. However, when using `dget()` I run into the following error message:

     `Error in initialize(value, ...) : could not find function ".local"`

Is this normal? This may be a simple fix.

Comment: I wrote another solution with `save()`